# Too many sources for User Profile information in O365, which is the source of truth

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, user-profile

There are several places to update User information in Office 365, but we would like to give users the ability to update their name and location instead of having an Admin do it all the time. In Delve, you cannot edit Contact information:

```
Office Nav bar => User name => My Profile => Update Profile => Contact Information
```

In Outlook, you can edit all fields:

https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/options/myaccount&IsDlg=1

In Office Portal, you can also edit all fields:

https://portal.office.com/account/#personalinfo

Since we have nothing on-premise, is Azure Active Directory the main source for all this info? If we get Users to update their info in OWA or `portal.office.com` , will that get pushed back to AAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one source for every user property. For example, profile photos do not all come from the same source. This article explains pretty well where some of the properties are synced from. https://blog.hyperfish.com/where-does-the-profile-information-come-from-in-office-365

As you suggested, Azure Active Directory is probably the best source for adding properties like name and location. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-profile-azure-portal

You can set up Owa or O365 to sync user properties with Azure AD but you need to configure that following the guide here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/configure-user-account-properties-with-office-365-powershell